# How to properly copy values from array to vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code that copies values from array to vector. But it does not work. In the last line I get

**error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream&&'
         cout << "s: " <<  tv << endl;**
              ^

```
int t[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> tv;

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    tv.push_back(i);

for (int v: tv)
    cout << "s: " <<  tv << endl;
```

Comment: `cout << "s: " <<  v << endl;`  Typo in the last line.

Comment: Stupid me. I was only concentrating on copping part, and trying pointers, references, auto, and others. :-)

Comment: That's ok... It happens for everyone of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more "proper" way, replace this code:

```
int t[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> tv;

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    tv.push_back(i);
```

with this:

```
const int t[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
const vector<int> tv( begin( t ), end( t ) );
```

where `begin` and `end` are `std::begin` and `std::end` from the `<iterator>` header.

---

Oh, the compilation error: simple typo, writing `tv` instead of `t`.

Comment: why does the `vector` need to be `const` ? In the original code it's non-const. Making it const makes it looks like it has to be constant.

Comment: @Jagannath: To save work, add `const` whereever possible. I.e. it's the default choice. One doesn't need a reason to use `const`, one needs a reason to not use `const`. Making it non-`const` makes it look like it has to change. Does it?

Comment: I agree with the default `const` choice. But sometimes these "almost always..." type of thumb-rules confuse the newbies ( not saying OP is a newbie ). So, I believe we should add a bit of explanation as well if we say this is "proper" way to do.

Answer (score 1):

At this line，

```
 cout << "s: " <<  tv << endl;
```

tv is `vector<int>` not `int`. Modify your code like this:

```
cout << "s: " << v << endl;
```

You can accept it now, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,I really need 50 rep score to Add Comment,forgive me